# Programming a GSM phone/modem to make phone calls

Tags: java, python, mobile, gsm, modem

I want to use a program written in a high level language like Java or Python to talk to a GSM Modem.

I want to be able to tell the modem what number to call and when to call it.  I also want to be able to read and send text messages.
I do NOT need to handle voice transmission in either direction of the call.

I'd appreciate recommendations of any applicable libraries and specific modems that are good to start with? I like Java but am willing to try something else.

Thanks

Comment: This is a place for problems, not research.

Comment: This is actually a problem...read the question

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=gsm+at+commands

Answer (score 3):

There are a set of relatively standard "AT" commands that can be used for these types of operations - including placing phone calls and sending text messages.  Some details around this are at http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/ and http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/ (simply first results of a little online searching).

A little more online searching yielded a Java-specific example at http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22 .

I had done a little bit of this in Java a number of years back, using the Java Communications API - available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html .  (My purpose was for interfacing with the phone book on my phone, but this also should have worked with interfacing with the SMS system.)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all modems and (phones which support tethering to your PC) can do this. All modems are equally good at it.There are no starter's modems. Just go through the AT commands specific to your applications and thats it.